# pass result query of report to drillthrough report as parameter

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, reporting-services, drillthrough

everyone!
Im facing a problem and hoped you could help me. So bassiclly I have to parse Data from MySql to Oracle, but the hard thing is have to do it through SSRS Reporting.

The situation is like this: I have a one report which returns query with a big list of names and also I have another report which takes a string as a parameter and makes an insert to oracleDB. So i hoped find solution maybe as a loop that takes every name from first report and pass it to second one, and I think that it should be done on "SSRS level"

UPD^: The question is: is there any chance to parse consequentially result query 
from first report to another

PS. the reason to make it within SSRS Report is caused by need of making all this operation by another people

Comment: We would love to help... But I don't see any question.

Comment: Im really sorry, this is my second time I ask on stackoverflow. And the first one wasnt good either.

Comment: In the dataset for report 1, create a Stored Procedure that inserts the names into a temporary table, and shows the data in the SSRS report.  In report 2, create a stored procedure that takes the results from the temporary table, and inserts them into the Oracle DB.  Thats the hard and fast way.  You need to be super careful with this though, and make sure you are not opening up a can of worms.

Comment: You mean for report 1 create Procedure in MySql? but I dont have any access to MySql, the only way I can have an access to that data is through reporting, you there is "Query Design" window

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have the query that returns the list of names you need?  Could you do a `JOIN` on the list of names, which will put them all into a ";" delimited string, pass that string as the parameter, and `Split` the string back into a list of names at the other end?

Comment: You see, Im getting the list from MySql DB, through the Visual Studio. As you know there is a "Query Designer" window, which allows you to edit your select query and even execute it.

Comment: And the othrer problem is the result query is too long. I found out that as parameter of SSRS report it (parameter) could store only 15 000 characters, but my query returns something like 10 000 names, and its mucj more than 15 000 characters. So I think passing result of a query to the parameter will cause losing some of the information